# IBM RFT Suddenly slower

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, rft

I have been using IBM's RFT for a short while now and the playback went really fast (nearly too fast to watch).
Then I went through a tutorial and changed the RFTs config (options in the menu) a bit (but not the response times) and now it pauses far longer between steps. I already set back everything to standard in the config but it's still that slow.

Anyone got a clue why?

My guess is that the default install values are faster than the "standard" values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RFT restart solved the issue. Seems it gets slower from time to time.